# why ZonedDateTime class does not implement TemporalAdjuster interface

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time

I'm currently studying java.time API and I have noticed that majority of class (e.g. `LocalDate`, `OffsetDateTime`) in java.time implement `TemporalAdjuster` interface, but `ZonedDateTime` does not. I was just wondering why this is the case? Why exclude `ZonedDateTime` from implementing `TemporalAdjuster` interface?

Comment: I think the reason is in the name of the interface. `ZonedDateTime` is not intended to serve as a modifier but as a given "value". Meanwhile anything which implements `TemporalAdjuster` is intended to adjust other "value"-objects.

Comment: Given that OffsetDateTime *does* implement TemporalAdjuster, I think it has something to do with daylight saving time switchovers and not knowing when they occur in the context of a Temporal. But I'm not betting on anyone else knowing the right answer before @JonSkeet jumps in.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt lol how could we live without JonSkeet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `TemporalAdjuster` changes another temporal object via the `TemporalAdjuster.adjustInto(Temporal)` method. The `Temporal` interface allows the individual fields to be altered via `Temporal.with(TemporalField, long)`.

`LocalDate` can implement `TemporalAdjuster` because its state consists entirely of temporal fields (year, month, day-of-month). As such, the implementation in `LocalDate.adjustInto(Temporal)` can call `Temporal.with(TemporalField, long)` passing the year, month and day (it actually uses `ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY`, which is a composite of year, month and day).

`OffsetDateTime` can implement `TemporalAdjuster` because its state also consists entirely of temporal fields (year, month, day-of-month, hour, minute, second, nanosecond and offset-seconds). Thus, again the implementation in `OffsetDateTime.adjustInto(Temporal)` can call `Temporal.with(TemporalField, long)` passing the fields one-by-one.

`ZonedDateTime` cannot implement `TemporalAdjuster` because its state includes a `ZoneId`, which is not a temporal field, thus cannot be passed to `Temporal.with(TemporalField, long)`. ie. it is not possible to change the time-zone of a temporal class via the `Temporal` interface.

Given that `ZonedDateTime` includes all the possible date-time fields, this restriction has little effect in practice.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `ZoneId` is not a `TemporalField`?

Comment: oh wow, can't believe I'm talking to the author of JodaTime. Thank you sir, for your contribution to JodaTime and the java.time.

Comment: `TemporalField` is used to refer to `long` numeric values. `ZoneId` is effectively a `String`. So, `ZoneId` cannot implement `TemporalField`.